# How to read NTFS drives in Linux (RHEL 6)?

Tags: rhel, mount, ntfs

My system is on dual boot. I have installed both RHEL 6 and win7 in it. I use RHEL mostly and I want to use my windows' NTFS drive in RHEL. How can I do it? Tell me the procedure.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very similar question seems to have been answered over at Super User.

https://superuser.com/questions/251663/unable-to-mount-ntfs-drive-with-rhel-6

Edit:

If you wanted to mount sda3 your command would look like this:

```
mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda3 /mnt/windows
```

For more information on ntfs-3g check out the site [here](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-download/).

Answer (score 1):

Install the `fuse ntfs-3g package` (if not available download it, remember your OS type 64-bit or 32-bit)

You must be logged in as `root` for the below command to work :

```
# yum install ntfs-3g
```

if yum is not configured install it by using rpm command.

Entering the below commands would help you determine the name of an NTFS partition :

```
# fdisk -l /dev/sda
# fdisk -l /dev/sdb
```

It is essential to load the fuse driver. The below command should help you do that :

```
 # modprobe fuse
```

Now using the below command you must build a mount point:

```
 # mkdir /mnt/ntfs
```

The following command would help you with mounting the ntfs partition :

```
 # mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /mnt/ntfs
```

This is a temporary mounting only, if you reboot your pc the mount point will be lost. To mount it permanently, you need to edit the `/etc/fstab` configuration file.

```
# vim /etc/fstab
```

in the file

```
ex: # device name   mount point     fs-type      options                 
/dev/sda6          /mnt/ntfs        ntfs-3g      auto          0 0
```

clear explanation for each column:

- device name - your partition name ex: /dev/sda6
- mount point - where u mount u r partition  ex: /mnt/ntfs
- fs-type - your file system type ex: ntfs-3g (if u give ntfs, may be it is not work)
- option - Ex:auto (if not work give it is defaults)

last two columns same as  0 0

Answer (score 0):

I don't have RHEL, but `yum install fuse-ntfs-3g` should work AFAIK.

Comment: Newer version is just named `ntfs-3g`, but yours still works. Better is `sudo yum install ntfs-3g ntfsprogs`.

Answer (score 0):

Only Few Packages which needs to be Installed and You are done.

1. Install and configure the EPEL Repository

   ```
   wget http://epel.mirror.net.in/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
   rpm -Uvh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
   ```
2. Install the packages related to NTFS Mount:

   ```
   yum -y install ntfs-3g ntfsprogs
   ```
3. Attach NTFS drive and find and mount partition:

   ```
   mount /dev/sda4 /etc/windows_ntfs
   ```

   Make sure before that "windows_ntfs" folder is created inside the etc folder

Comment: Please add the missing part @siva-s-tenet

Comment: @polym You can directly double click the drive or mount it to some folder

Answer (score 0):

This process worked for me:

In RHEL developer edition which is free subscription,

```
yum install ntfs-3g
```

didn't work for me. I had to manually add epel repository through

```
yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
```

then, `yum install ntfs-3g` worked.

After that, i've mounted partitions through:

`mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda5 /mnt/ntfs`

References:

[1] https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=4722

[2] http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL