# How to mount remote file system

Tags: rhel, mount, ext4, ntfs

I want to mount my Windows `NTFS` share C:\ to Linux `ext4` file system, so I can see the file system tree as part of my Linux file system and transfer my files.

PS. I am using `rhel6`.

Comment: The question / wish description does not make sense. A file system can be mounted to a mount point only but not to another file system (even if it accesses another one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Hauke Laging says, it will not become ext4, but you could mount it to /mnt/winshare or some other place, using Samba. A tutorial for RHE is [here](http://www.firewall.cx/linux-knowledgebase-tutorials/system-and-network-services/848-linux-services-samba.html). Both ways (linux to windows, and vice versa) are described.
BTW: [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16893/how-to-read-ntfs-drives-in-linux-rhel-6?rq=1) seems to be a similar question.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is another alternative.  Microsoft has a package that enables NFS on a Windows box, thus you could setup NFS on the Windows box and then mount via NFS on the UNIX box.  This probably involves some investigation and work on your part.

Of course, there are permissions errors.

If all you want is to transfer files, you might want to consider a simple choice ... that of using a USB memory stick.  Plug in to windows, transfer files, unplug gracefully in windows, plugin to Linux, transfer files.  Might be a lot easier.